# Continuous piping in bash program

Tags: bash

I'm looking for a way to pipe text continuously into a process like `write`. I do **not** want to buffer and pipe it all at once. This is my bash script so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `seq 1 10`; do
    echo $i | write user
done
```

The problem is that `write` gets opened and closed `i` times. Does anyone know how I can keep it alive while looping?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, just move the pipe outside the loop:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `seq 1 10`; do
    echo "$i"
done | write user
```

As you've tagged with [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), I would suggest using a brace expansion `for i in {1..10}` rather than calling `seq`. If the numbers are variable, you can use something like `for (( i = a; i < b; ++i ))`.